# How to unzip XCode.xip downloads? Archive Utility gets stuck at the end

Tags: macos, finder, archive

I've downloaded the 7.68 GB Xcode_14.2.xip file from http://developer.apple.com/downloads onto a 60 GB USB drive.

I double-clicked it to expand it using macOS' built-in Archive Utility.

However, both times I've tried this process so far, Archive Utility gets stuck after the bar is full:

[image]

It takes a couple hours at most to reach this point, but then it remains frozen like this for more than 12 hours.

According to [Archive Utility has stopped working](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4381241?sortBy=best) and [Archive Utility freezes when trying to unzip a zip file](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4386915?sortBy=best) I wanted to try deleting com.apple.archiveutility.plist, but neither ~/Library/Preferences nor /Library/Preferences include such a file for me. I'm on macOS Monterey.

I've also tried running Disk Utility's First Aid on the Thumb drive as another answer suggested, but "The Volume Thumb drive appears to be OK".

Apart from installing a third party unarchiver, how might I be able to expand that Xcode xip file?

Comment: If you can copy the archive to the internal storage (or another external device), try expanding it there.

Comment: @LincD. Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately in my case I downloaded it onto the thumb drive because my own hard drive doesn't have enough storage left.

Comment: Then I suggest you free up some space, at least temporarily. You're asking a lot of a thumb drive.

Comment: FWIW: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.archiveutility/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.archiveutility.plist` (com.apple.archiveutility=Archive Utility in Finder).  Not that I think it would make a difference, deleting it.